# Comida: picante vs picor

Tags: diferencias-regionales

Hoy día escuché el término "comida sin picor" para referirse a "comida no picante". En mi caso nunca antes había escuchado el término "picor".

¿En qué países se usa el término "picor"? ¿Qué tan común o formal es esa palabra?

Comment: En España _picor_ es esa sensación tan incómoda en la piel que nos hace _rascarnos_. Si oimos _comida con picor_ lo que nos sugiere es que, tras ingerirla, nos produce una reacción alérgica o algo así que provoca picor. Claramente, es un significado distinto al que te refieres sin relación con que la comida sea _picante_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la frase es desafortunada en cualquier país.

Picor, según el diccionario de la RAE es la "desazón que causa algo que pica" o el "escozor que resulta en el paladar por haber comido algo picante".

**La comida no siente** desazón ni escozor. Lo siente el comensal.

"Comida picante" es "comida que pica" o  "comida que **produce** picor". Pero "comida con picor" sería "comida que siente picor".

Quizás se vea más claro con algo diferente: Hay "mosquitos que pican" o "mosquitos que producen picor" o pero "mosquitos con picor" serían insectos con urticaria, que en lugar de buscar a sus víctimas se dedicarían a rascarse las antenas.

Por otra parte, en mi opinión no es comparable "comida con picor"  a "comida con sabor" . El sabor sí es una clara propiedad de la comida (la comida sí tiene sabor), lo mismo que hay mosquitos alados o "mosquitos con alas".

Answer (score 2):

No muy común, en mi experiencia (Argentina), pero tampoco muy desusado. En el ejemplo que traes, el paralelo sería:

> Comida **picante** = Comida con **picor**
>      Comida **sabrosa** = Comida con **sabor**

En general, la primera forma, con el adjetivo, es más llana y, en mi opinión, preferible.

"**Picor**" es aquí un sustantivo que, a diferencia del "sabor" de mi ejemplo, es ambiguo, porque puede referirse tanto a una cualidad de la comida (ese algo que lo hace ser picante), como también a la **sensación** que esa comida nos provoca. En este último sentido se puede asimilar a "**picazón**" ([ej](http://belleza.uncomo.com/articulo/como-tratar-el-picor-de-la-piel-4907.html)), aunque esta última se aplica sobre todo a sensaciones táctiles, más que gustativas.

Para terminar de complicarla, hay que recordar que "**picante**" también se usa como sustantivo: la sustancia que se agrega a la comida para hacerla picante. Así que *"una  comida con picante"*  es normalmente *"una comida picante"* (pero estas dos expresiones no son sinónimas).

Answer (score 1):

En mi experiencia (Guatemala y Centro América), se usa las palabras **picante** o **con chile**.  Independientemente de si el origen del picante es chile o no.

> Comida con chile
>    Comida picante

Comment: ¿Estas seguro? Usualmente yo si hago la diferencia entre con chile y simplemente picante o condimentado, si el _picor_ no proviene de un chile, y provengo de la misma región.